# How to join/connect/group multiple objects in Mayavi2

Tags: python, vtk, enthought, mayavi

I would like to combine multiple Mayavi objects into a single "grouped" object so that I control all of their properties together. For example I created the following bi-convex lens shape by combining 3 built-in surfaces (two spheres and one cylinder). Now I would like to assign uniform properties (specularity, ambient color, etc) to all of the constituent surfaces at a time (not individually). Also, I would like to translate/rotate the lens as a whole. I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Here is the bi-convex lens created in Mayavi (code given below):

[image]

As it can be seen in the following figure, the above lens is composed of three surfaces:

[image]

---

Here is the code for building the bi-convex lens:

---

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
from mayavi.sources.builtin_surface import BuiltinSurface
from mayavi.modules.surface import Surface
from mayavi.filters.transform_data import TransformData


def lensUsingMayaviBuiltinSphere(radius=0.5, semiDiam=0.25, thickness=0.9):
    """
    Render a bi-convex lens
    """
    engine = mlab.get_engine()
    sag = radius - np.sqrt(radius**2 - semiDiam**2)
    cyl_height = thickness - 2.0*sag   # thickness of the cylinder in between
    # Create Mayavi data sources -- sphere_h1_src, sphere_h2_src, cylinder_src    
    # half 1: source = sphere_h1_src
    sphere_h1_src = BuiltinSurface()
    engine.add_source(sphere_h1_src)
    sphere_h1_src.source = 'sphere'
    sphere_h1_src.data_source.radius = radius
    sphere_h1_src.data_source.center = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  -np.sqrt(radius**2 - semiDiam**2) + cyl_height/2.0])
    sphere_h1_src.data_source.end_phi = np.rad2deg(np.arcsin(semiDiam/radius)) #60.0
    sphere_h1_src.data_source.end_theta = 360.0
    sphere_h1_src.data_source.phi_resolution = 300
    sphere_h1_src.data_source.theta_resolution = 300
    # half 2: source = sphere_h2_src
    sphere_h2_src = BuiltinSurface()
    engine.add_source(sphere_h2_src)
    sphere_h2_src.source = 'sphere'
    sphere_h2_src.data_source.radius = radius
    sphere_h2_src.data_source.center = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  np.sqrt(radius**2 - semiDiam**2) - cyl_height/2.0])
    sphere_h2_src.data_source.start_phi = 180.0 - np.rad2deg(np.arcsin(semiDiam/radius))
    sphere_h2_src.data_source.end_phi = 180.0
    sphere_h2_src.data_source.end_theta = 360.0
    sphere_h2_src.data_source.phi_resolution = 300
    sphere_h2_src.data_source.theta_resolution = 300
    # cylinder source data in between 
    cylinder_src = BuiltinSurface()
    engine.add_source(cylinder_src)
    cylinder_src.source = 'cylinder'
    cylinder_src.data_source.center = np.array([ 0.,  0.,  0.])
    if cyl_height > 0:
        cylinder_src.data_source.height = cyl_height
    else:
        cylinder_src.data_source.height = 0.0
    cylinder_src.data_source.radius = semiDiam
    cylinder_src.data_source.capping = False
    cylinder_src.data_source.resolution = 50

    # Add transformation filter to align cylinder length along z-axis
    transform_data_filter = TransformData()
    engine.add_filter(transform_data_filter, cylinder_src)
    Rt_c = [ 1.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.00,
             0.0000,  0.0000, -1.0000,  0.00,
             0.0000,  1.0000,  0.0000,  0.00, 
             0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  1.00]
    transform_data_filter.transform.matrix.__setstate__({'elements': Rt_c})
    transform_data_filter.widget.set_transform(transform_data_filter.transform)
    transform_data_filter.filter.update()
    transform_data_filter.widget.enabled = False   # disable the rotation control further.

    # Add surface modules to each source
    right_surface = Surface()
    engine.add_filter(right_surface, sphere_h1_src)
    left_surface = Surface()
    engine.add_filter(left_surface, sphere_h2_src)
    cyl_surface = Surface()
    engine.add_filter(cyl_surface, transform_data_filter)


fig = mlab.figure()
# Add lens
lensUsingMayaviBuiltinSphere(radius=2, semiDiam=1.2)
mlab.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to combine sources in the way you are looking for. I think in fact that is probably impossible since under the hood the `BuiltinSurface` object has specific vtk sources that are not what you want. It should however be possible to simply use a different source that gives what you want. In this case you could generate a biconvex lens with `mlab.mesh`:

```
a,c,h=3,1,.2

phi,theta = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:np.pi/250, 0:2*np.pi:np.pi/250]
x=a*np.cos(theta)*np.sin(phi)
y=a*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi)
z=c*np.cos(phi)+(h*(-1)**(np.cos(phi)<0))

mlab.mesh(x,y,z,color=(1,1,1)
mlab.show()
```

[image]

One minor difference is that this surface is smooth. This is the nature of sampling a single surface --i.e., this result is a direct consequence of what your question asks to do. If this is an important feature of your figure, I would suggest an entirely different approach: wrap the 3 sources in a class and have the event handler update the relevant attributes on all three.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will surely try the second methods that you have suggested sometime later. For now, I am trying to make do with the solution 1. However, I think the line `z=c*np.cos(phi)*(h*(-1)**(np.cos(phi)<0))` is probably missing a piece. Could you please double check? Also, your example inspired me add a few things to get the "edges" that I wanted. I am putting that code and figure into a separate answer (as the comment section is really small)

Comment: Yes it should have been `z=c*np.cos(phi)+(h*(-1)**(np.cos(phi)<0))`, `+` not `*`. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code by @aestrivex, here is one way of getting the desired output (lens with sharp edges). Note that this is not a solution for connecting multiple Mayavi objects.

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab

# Control parameters
# r is the semi-diameter of the lens 
# c controls the center thickness of the lens
# h controls the curvature of the surfaces (lesser the value more the curvature)

r, c, h = 3, .75, .9 

delta_phi = np.pi/250.0             # phi == azimuth  (0 <= phi <= pi)
delta_theta = np.pi/100.0           # theta == zenith (0 <= theta <= pi)
phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:2.0*np.pi + delta_phi:delta_phi,0:np.pi + delta_theta:delta_theta]
# The Exact threshold values for masking tz, txy will change depending upon the
# sampling of theta. txy is always slightly less than tz. tz should be around 0.3
tz, txy = 0.279, 0.275
x = r*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi)*(np.abs(np.cos(theta)) > txy)
y = r*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi)*(np.abs(np.cos(theta)) > txy)
z = c*np.cos(theta)*(h**(-1)*( np.abs(np.cos(theta)) > tz))

mlab.mesh(x,y,z,color=(1,1,1))

mlab.show()
```

And here is the output:
[image]