# MayaVi points3d with specified individual colors

Tags: python-2.7, colors, 3d, rendering, mayavi

I want to render some 3d spheres and to specify for each of it size and color. With size I have no problem:

```
import mayavi.mlab as mlab
import numpy as np
#white background
mlab.figure(fgcolor=(0., 0., 0.), bgcolor=(1, 1, 1))
#coordinates and sizes
x1     = np.array([27.340, 26.266, 26.913, 27.886, 25.112])
y1     = np.array([24.430, 25.413, 26.639, 26.463, 24.880])
z1     = np.array([2.614, 2.842, 3.531, 4.263, 3.649])
#initial size
size1  = np.array([7, 6, 6, 8, 6])
#decrease size of the spheres
size = np.true_divide(size1, 9)
#create spheres
mlab.points3d(x1, y1, z1, size, resolution=60, scale_factor=1)
#draw
mlab.show()
```

Gives OK spheres, but is impossible to control the colors.
[image]

I want to recolor depending of the `size1` values

```
colors = []
for i in size1:
    if i == 6 :
        colors.append([0.5, 0.5, 0.5]) # grey
    elif i == 7:
        colors.append([0.1, 0.1, 0.9]) # blue
    elif i == 8:
        colors.append([0.9, 0.1, 0.1]) # red
```

I have seen similar problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32684960/1651481) but I use `points3d` and there is no solution which I can use for my case.

How to define color for the each 3d point/sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found an option how to deal with this problem - redraw `mlab.points3d` multiple times.
And create lists for different colors:

```
list_grey = []
list_red = []
list_blue = []

for i in range(np.count_nonzero(size1)):
    if size1[i] == 6 :
        list_grey.append(i)
    elif size1[i] == 7:
        list_blue.append(i)
    elif size1[i] == 8:
        list_red.append(i)

mlab.points3d(x1[list_grey], y1[list_grey], z1[list_grey], size[list_grey], resolution=60, scale_factor=1, color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
mlab.points3d(x1[list_blue], y1[list_blue], z1[list_blue], size[list_blue], resolution=60, scale_factor=1, color=(0.1, 0.1, 0.9))
mlab.points3d(x1[list_red], y1[list_red], z1[list_red], size[list_red], resolution=60, scale_factor=1, color=(0.9, 0.1, 0.1))
```

[image]